# Git - Switching branches causes conflicts

Tags: git

When I'm on my develop branch and pull the latest, and then switch to a feature branch I get a bunch of merge conflicts despite there being no uncommitted changes.

What's even more strange is that the changes aren't coming from the develop branch, they seem to be from an old commit that's long gone and the files since changed a dozen times.

I have tried to keep the current branches changes and then merge the feature branch into develop, I thought this would resolve the conflict, but it happens again after the branches get merged.

Comment: Can you post a list of git commands that you are running in order?

Comment: A switch command doesn't generate conflicts unless you're using some specific params (`-m` maybe?). Do you mean that you got conflicts when you pulled, preventing you from switching?

Comment: If `develop` is used only as a target to merge feature branches into, you should not _have_ a local `develop` branch in the first place.

Comment: @DavidWebb I am using the visual studio git functionality so unfortunately no, but i assume that in the background it should only be running git checkout

Comment: @RomainValeri No the checkout isnt prevented, I checkout the branch and then in the git changes window it shows me a list of conflicted files which I have to choose which to take, incoming or current. But the develop branch is clean, nothing to commit or stashed etc

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a file that is not tracked on your current branch but that is tracked on your other branch.

Type `git status` and you should notice there are untracked files.

This should not be a problem, as those files are usually kept when you switch branches: it's like if they weren't even noticed by Git.

Unfortunately, the branch you want to switch to has tracked that file and therefore will override it. As you could possibly lose some code by switching, Git prevents you from doing this action.

To solve this problem:

- If you don't care about the untracked files, delete them before switching.
- If you care about the untracked files and they need to be in the current branch, add and commit them before switching.
- If you care about the untracked files but don't want them in the current branch, use `git stash` to save them in a temporary branch that you can "paste" in another branch with `git stash pop` (look into it before doing it).

Comment: I dont think this is correct, the files dont show as untracked in the develop branch. The develop branch before switching has nothing to commit, it isnt used as a working branch, it is merely branch off of for feature development.

Comment: Too bad then, that was the most promising explanation. If you don't mind, I'll leave the answer as it could be a problem that others encounter. If you provide more context, I'll try to figure it out!